# Paypal Balance Accounts API - INSUFFICIENT_PRIVILEGES

Tags: paypal

i'm trying to access paypals accounts using the rest api

i'm making a request to /v2/wallet/balance-accounts/ ( Documentation : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/balance-accounts/)

but keep getting the following message:

```
Array
(
    [name] => INSUFFICIENT_PRIVILEGES
    [message] => Insufficient privileges for requested resource.
    [information_link] => 
    [details] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [issue] => Insufficient privileges for requested resource.
                    [code] => INSUFFICIENT_PRIVILEGES
                )

        )

)
```

does anyone know from where i can change/add the privileges? i can't find the settings for it

thank you

Comment: hi, have you find the solution? Because I am stuck with the similar problem.

Comment: sorry, no solution found, i wanted to check if there is enough balance when trying to make a refund...

you still try to make a refund , and if there isn't enough balance you will get an error , somethign like "insufficient funds"

Comment: yes, #metoo. It seems the only solution is to use PayPal Sync but it updates the balance with the huge delay

Comment: I found that in PayPal SDK you can catch the ResourceInvalid exception which is raised when there are no sufficient funds, and then inform the client about it:
```
try:
    if payout.create():
        print("payout[%s] created successfully" %
              (payout.batch_header.payout_batch_id))
    else:
        print(payout.error)

except ResourceInvalid as e:
    err_body=json.loads(e.content)
    print(err_body['name'])
    print(err_body['message'])
```

Comment: I am also stuck with this problem. Perhaps somehow we need to link the account to the app? (via Oauth?) It seems like `Balance Accounts API` is meant to work for multiple accounts (I just want to get my *own* balance).

Answer (score 1):

It says [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.payouts-batch/#payouts) you must have a business account, and also [here](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Everything-Else-REST/How-to-get-the-balance-of-my-PayPal-account-using-API/m-p/1442651/highlight/true#M89) (you must be a partner) based on their suggestion [here](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Everything-Else-REST/How-to-get-the-balance-of-my-PayPal-account-using-API/m-p/1443712/highlight/true#M92) you have an alternative:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetBalance_API_Operation_NVP/

Which is unfortunately not REST

Hope this helps